# Is it OK to ask the recruiter whether the technical interview will be a whiteboard coding interview?

Tags: interviewing

I have a technical interview next week and I don't have much information about it. The only thing I would like to know is whether it is a whiteboard coding interview or just some general technical questions about CS, since I have experienced many other technical interviews which did not ask me to code at all. I just want to know is it OK to ask the recruiter whether it is a whiteboard coding interview or not.

Comment: Note that the recruiter might or might not know how the interview. The company I work for does not tell the recruiters how they will interview.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's fine.

Just drop the recruiter an email and ask if you could have "some details on the format of the interview" so that you can prepare properly.

Nobody is going to raise any eyebrows over this.

Comment: *"some details on the format of the interview"* - Maybe something specific like, *"Will there be any programming and what setting?"*